# How to Serialize complex entities in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to serialize vehicle entity which has multiple entities associated with it.

```
/**
 * Vehicle
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicle")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\Repository\VehicleRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Vehicle {

       public function __construct(){
            $this->car = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->bus = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->truc = new ArrayCollection();
        }
    //....
    }
```

I have tried this in my controller

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
$reports = $serializer->serialize($vehicle, 'json');
print_r( $reports);exit;
return new Response($reports);
```

it gives me this error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

As I am new to symfony, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **I also had some trouble with the symfony serializer, I use https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle**

Answer (score 0):

I had to this exact same thing at work a few weeks ago when writing a data backup/restore script.

In the end I used [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) which is awesome.

You can specify output type, and also, very importantly depth settings, to avoid recursive nesting issues when dealing with relationships.

[Usage](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/usage) is very straight forward, but you'll need to add depth annotations in your entities and then tell the serializer to use them as follows:

**entity**

```
/**
 * @MaxDepth(2)
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
private $tags;
```

**controller**

```
$this->serializer = $this->getContainer()->get( 'jms_serializer' );

$output = $this->serializer->serialize( $entities, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks() )
```

you can specify output type.  In this case I used json as I was constructing a data file, but you can easily output to standard array.

Hope that helps.